# Java add ActionListener to special button

Tags: java, swing, overriding, action, windowlistener

Is there a way to add/override the action event of [THIS](http://i44.tinypic.com/2hy9dz9.jpg) button ? I couldn't find anywhere how to acces this button and override it's action. In my case I need to do this because I need to save the resources before I exit my window, and if I press the x button, It will exit automatically.

Comment: Uh...we definitely need more information. What kind of component is the button? A Swing component?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the JFrame:

```
setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
```

Then add a WindowsListener and in the `windowClosing(WindowEvent event)` methods do your job and then call `dispose()`

Answer (score 3):

I'd use a shut-down hook instead that way it'll save even if you close the app via another method.
[Looky here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5824049/running-a-method-when-closing-the-program)

Answer (score 2):

You can try using a WindowListener interface. If I remember correctly, it should allow you to do things when something on the frame is clicked on(like exiting).

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/WindowListener.html