# Execute method at shutdown throws log4j illegal state exception unable to register shutdown

Tags: java, log4j, shutdown-hook

I'd like to close connections when exiting the swing application.
So as suggested here: [Running a method when closing the program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5824049/running-a-method-when-closing-the-program)

I added following code, in the main to the main thread, ending up with following stack trace. It does perform my closeConnections method.

```
/** on exit */
         Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(new Runnable() {

                public void run() {
                     DeviceManager.getInstance().closeConnections();
                    //shutdown log4j2
                    if( LogManager.getContext() instanceof LoggerContext ) {
                        LogManager.getLogger().info("Shutting down log4j2");
                        Configurator.shutdown((LoggerContext)LogManager.getContext());
                    } else{
                        LogManager.getLogger().warn("Unable to shutdown log4j2");}

                }

            }, "Shutdown-thread"));

ERROR StatusLogger catching java.lang.IllegalStateException: Shutdown in progress
    at java.lang.ApplicationShutdownHooks.add(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.addShutdownHook(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.util.DefaultShutdownCallbackRegistry.addShutdownHook(DefaultShutdownCallbackRegistry.java:136)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.util.DefaultShutdownCallbackRegistry.start(DefaultShutdownCallbackRegistry.java:125)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.initializeShutdownCallbackRegistry(Log4jContextFactory.java:123)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.<init>(Log4jContextFactory.java:89)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.<init>(Log4jContextFactory.java:54)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.<clinit>(LogManager.java:96)
    at com.guitarjwindows.repositories.midi.WindowsMidiCommunicator.init(WindowsMidiCommunicator.java:46)
    at com.guitarjwindows.repositories.midi.WindowsMidiCommunicator.<init>(WindowsMidiCommunicator.java:33)
    at com.guitarjwindows.repositories.midi.WindowsMidiCommunicator.getInstance(WindowsMidiCommunicator.java:37)
    at com.guitarjwindows.service.DeviceManager.closeConnections(DeviceManager.java:35)
    at com.guitarjwindows.starter.Starter$1.run(Starter.java:33)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

2015-05-05 13:30:24,505 FATAL Unable to register shutdown hook because JVM is shutting down.
[INFO ] 2015-05-05 13:30:24.515 [Shutdown-thread] WindowsMidiCommunicator - Max receivers:0
[INFO ] 2015-05-05 13:30:24.516 [Shutdown-thread] WindowsMidiCommunicator - 2- Saffire 6USBobtained as inputDevice
[INFO ] 2015-05-05 13:30:24.516 [Shutdown-thread] WindowsMidiCommunicator - Max transmitters:-1
[INFO ] 2015-05-05 13:30:24.516 [Shutdown-thread] WindowsMidiCommunicator - Open receivers:
[INFO ] 2015-05-05 13:30:24.516 [Shutdown-thread] WindowsMidiCommunicator - No default receiver
[INFO ] 2015-05-05 13:30:24.516 [Shutdown-thread] WindowsMidiCommunicator - Open transmitters:
[INFO ] 2015-05-05 13:30:24.517 [Shutdown-thread] WindowsMidiCommunicator - Default transmitter: com.sun.media.sound.MidiInDevice$MidiInTransmitter@151107e
[INFO ] 2015-05-05 13:30:24.517 [Shutdown-thread] WindowsMidiCommunicator - Open transmitters now:
[INFO ] 2015-05-05 13:30:24.517 [Shutdown-thread] WindowsMidiCommunicator - com.sun.media.sound.MidiInDevice$MidiInTransmitter@151107e
[INFO ] 2015-05-05 13:30:24.518 [Shutdown-thread] WindowsMidiCommunicator - Max receivers:-1
[INFO ] 2015-05-05 13:30:24.518 [Shutdown-thread] WindowsMidiCommunicator - 2- Saffire 6USBobtained as outputDevice
[INFO ] 2015-05-05 13:30:24.518 [Shutdown-thread] WindowsMidiCommunicator - Max transmitters:0
[INFO ] 2015-05-05 13:30:24.518 [Shutdown-thread] WindowsMidiCommunicator - Open receivers:
[INFO ] 2015-05-05 13:30:24.518 [Shutdown-thread] WindowsMidiCommunicator - Default receiver: com.sun.media.sound.MidiOutDevice$MidiOutReceiver@1716ab5
[INFO ] 2015-05-05 13:30:24.518 [Shutdown-thread] WindowsMidiCommunicator - Open receivers now:
[INFO ] 2015-05-05 13:30:24.518 [Shutdown-thread] WindowsMidiCommunicator - com.sun.media.sound.MidiOutDevice$MidiOutReceiver@1716ab5
[INFO ] 2015-05-05 13:30:24.518 [Shutdown-thread] WindowsMidiCommunicator - Open transmitters:
[ERROR] 2015-05-05 13:30:24.518 [Shutdown-thread] WindowsMidiCommunicator - No default transmitter
[INFO ] 2015-05-05 13:30:24.571 [Shutdown-thread] WindowsMidiCommunicator - outputDevice closed
[INFO ] 2015-05-05 13:30:24.572 [Shutdown-thread] WindowsMidiCommunicator - inputDevice closed
2015-05-05 13:30:24,599 FATAL Unable to register shutdown hook because JVM is shutting down.
[INFO ] 2015-05-05 13:30:24.600 [Shutdown-thread] Starter$1 - Shutting down log4j2
```

Comment: Try get the LoggerContext state and test on it before shuting it down: (LoggerContext)LogManager.getContext().getState()

Comment: @jMounir  getState() method doesn't exist the way you suggest.  It's log4j2

Comment: Sorry I was mistaken, its should be called like this: ((LoggerContext)LogManager.getContext()).getState()

Comment: @jMounir I've added it  at the top of the run method.  I get State = started.  The error as shown in the original post is shown before the "state = started" printout.

Comment: Where have put this code. cause i see the comment `/** on exit */` do you mean the on exit event ?. because you cannot register a shutdown hook when the program is performin a shutdown. here what is said in the documentation: _Once the shutdown sequence has begun it is impossible to register a new shutdown hook or de-register a previously-registered hook. Attempting either of these operations will cause an IllegalStateException to be thrown._   from http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html

Comment: @jMounir  I've put the code directly in the main thread.   The /** onexit**/  is to indicate that this happens on exit.

Answer (score 0):

I think the log4j also has a shutdown hook and the order of the execution of shutdwon hook decided by the JVM, so you can not influence it. I might be possible to disable log4j shutdownhook and do the cleanup yourself, but it might be better to check what log4j does.