# Call Stop Thread method when JVM termiates

Tags: java, multithreading, scheduledexecutorservice

below is my Thread code. I want to call stopThread()  method when I terminates JVM. Please suggest right way to do.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
            ScheduledExecutorService scheduledExecutor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(10);
            for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
            scheduledExecutor.submit(new MyRunnable())
          }
         scheduledExecutor.shotdown()
        .....
}  

public class MyRunnable implements Runnable
{
      boolean isRunning = true;
      public void run()
      {
           while(isRunning)
          {
           Thread.sleep(5000);
         } 
      }
      public void stopThread()
      {
          isRunning = false;
      }
}
```

Comment: `isRunning` must be declared `volatile`, otherwise the JIT could optimize the loop to `while (true)`, and/or changes are not guaranteed to be visible to other threads.

Comment: You should add a shutdown hook, as described here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5824049/running-a-method-when-closing-the-program Note that this is not *guaranteed* to run - and there is no way to run code that's guaranteed to run on shutdown. The JVM might crash or be instantly killed (e.g. by *nix OOM killer).

Comment: To properly shut down your executor service, either (a) use try-with-resources syntax or (b) use the boilerplate code given to you in the `ExecutorService` Javadoc.

Comment: Obligatory Java Language Specification link:  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se21/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.3

Comment: What does "...when I terminates JVM" mean? You cannot count on anything happening in the JVM if you forcibly kill the process from a shell or, from any other process.